# Running function after transition is finished, that is caused by click event. (event in event)

Tags: javascript

After clicking the button the block gets a .red class with transition. I need to run a func after this transition is finished. Here is my code:

```
<button>PRESS</button>
<div class="test"></div>
```

---

```
.test {
  background-color: grey;
  height: 250px;
}
.red {
   background: red;
   transition: all 5s ease;
}
```

---

```
const btn = document.querySelector('button'),
      block = document.querySelector('.test');

btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  block.classList.add('red');
  foo();
})

function foo() {
  block.addEventListener('webkitTransitionEnd otransitionend oTransitionEnd 
  msTransitionEnd transitionend', function() {
  block.classList.remove('red');
 })
}
```

https://codepen.io/MrCodeBlog/pen/xpaNQZ?editors=1010

Comment: Ok, what's the question?

Comment: Just see my answer. If you use other than FF, just change string for event type. For webkit use webkitTransitionEnd, for opera oTransitionEnd and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Event type need to be a string for each event. So you can do like this.

```
function foo() {
  [
    'webkitTransitionEnd',
    'otransitionend',
    'oTransitionEnd',
    'msTransitionEnd',
    'transitionend',
  ].forEach(function(transition) {
    block.addEventListener(transition, function() {
      block.classList.remove('red');
    });
  });
}
```

Fiddle: https://codepen.io/dartist21/pen/MrqNWJ

Answer (score 0):

You can't pass all events at once, that is because it does not work. You need to add each individually. To FF is as follows:

```
function foo() {
    block.addEventListener('transitionend', function() {
    block.classList.remove('red');
  })
}
```

This updated fiddle work perfectly on Mozilla: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/aEagjy?editors=1010

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need a [`setTimeout()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout). Using setTimeout, you can run a block of code after a set amount of time. In your example you would just wrap `foo()` in a `setTimeout()` with 5000ms.

```
btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  block.classList.add('red');
  // The number is in ms so 5000ms is equal to the 5s it
  // takes for your CSS transition to finish.
  setTimeout(foo, 5000);
})
```